# Discord.js error when creating webhook with bot in Node.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots, webhooks

I am getting the following error when creating a webhook with my bot in Node.js.

Node v18.12.1
Discord.js version 14.7.1

Error:
the error was DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required

Code:

```
  let channelNumObj = client.channels.cache.get(channelNumVariable);

  const webhook = async () => {
    try {
      if (channelNumObj !== null) {
        await channelNumObj
          .createWebhook("Snek", {
            name: "Snek",
            avatar: "http://i.imgur.com/mI8XcpG.jpg",
            reason: "Needed a cool new Webhook",
          })
          .then(() => {
            console.log("completed");
          });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`the error was ${err}`);
    }
  };
  webhook();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  The problem was I was looking at the Discord.js docs for the previous version.  The updated docs had the updated syntax.  Here is the updated syntax for my version of Discord.js which is the latest version at the time of this post.

Note the syntax change where "Snek" is.

```
let channelNumObj = client.channels.cache.get(channelNumVariable);

  const webhook = async () => {
    try {
      if (channelNumObj !== null) {
        await channelNumObj
          .createWebhook({
            name: 'Snek',
            avatar: "http://i.imgur.com/mI8XcpG.jpg",
            reason: "Needed a cool new Webhook",
          })
          .then(() => {
            console.log("completed");
          })
          .catch(console.error)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`the error was ${err}`);
    }
  };
  webhook();
});
```